# Why do we pass the reference of the lower level stream in the higher level stream constructor?

Tags: java, io, stream

How exactly higher level stream works? Why do we wrap higher level around lower level stream? Higher level streams takes data from the lower level streams(since they cannot directly access file),then how they are more efficient than lower level streams?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. An example would really help. Who says that higher level streams are more efficient than low level streams? Usually they're used to provide extra functionality (encryption, compression etc) rather than efficiency...

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but we generally go for higher level streams when we want to increase the efficiency of the the read and write operation.

Comment: Again, if you could use an *example* it would be easier to answer you. It's entirely possible that we're thinking of a different meaning of "higher level stream"

Comment: Java BufferedOutputStream class uses an internal buffer to store data. It adds more efficiency than to write data directly into a stream. So, it makes the performance fast. source :http://www.javatpoint.com/BufferedInputStream-and-BufferedOutputStream

Comment: Right, so that's *one* higher level stream - BufferedOutputStream - which is indeed designed for efficiency by reducing the number of calls to the underlying streams. However, you seem to be asking a more general question about higher level streams.

Comment: @jon Yes, you're right I was wrong .Thanks..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you wrap an input or output stream (Not to be confused with the Java 8 Stream API) you notionally transform that stream so that when you read it, you deal witht he transformed data rather than the raw data.

> How exactly higher level stream works?

Each stream serves a simple purpose e.g. buffering, compression, encryption.  This is not magic , it just does it's job and passing the data on the lower level stream or visa versa when reading.

> Why do we wrap higher level around lower level stream?

This is the simplest way to build more complex streams.

> how they are more efficient than lower level streams?

It's not about efficiency (except for the buffered stream which is designed to minimise the number of system calls which are relatively expensive)

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your first question. We pass lower level stream to the constructor of a higher level stream since the high level stream needs the reference to the lower level stream in order to access the data.

As to your second question, high level streams can become more efficient by minimizing the access to the lower level stream they are wrapping. For example, BufferedOutputStream minimizes the writes to the stream that it wraps by maintaining a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The higher level streams are not more efficient just... higher level. They give you a more usable interface for practical tasks. For example instead of reading byte by byte checking for the new line character you simply read a whole line. Underneath the higher level streams call methods of the lower level ones, that's why you have to pass one to them to operate on.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example to explain. Ultimately everything should be passed as bytes. For a programmer It is very hard to deal with the bytes always in his programme. So high level streams comes into picture where you just pass your element and internal work done by low level stream.

```
My program .....>High Level Stream  ....> Low level Stream ......>(bytes)....> external/other target
```